# Modify the Hover Panel on the search page

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template

I would like to customize the hover panel that is shown when I'm over an item on the result page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possibile.
You have to modify a file under *Master pages and page layouts* of your site.
When you click there you will have a list of directory. So go trough:

Display Templates -> Search -> Item_Default_HoverPanel.js

My suggestion is have a copy of that file and the *Item_Default.js* on your system. Rename those like My_Item_Default* and do your customization.

This is an example:

```
    ctx [ 'DisplayTemplateData' ] [ 'ManagedPropertyMapping' ] = {
    'AccountName' : [ 'AccountName' ],
    'AskMeAbout' : [ 'myCustomProperty' ],
//...

        var has_askme = !$isEmptyString ( ctx.CurrentItem.AskMeAbout );

// ...

        if ( has_askme === true ) {
            ms_outHtml.push ( '                        ', '                              <div id="askmeabout">' + ctx.CurrentItem.AskMeAbout + '</div>' );
        }
```

Comment: how should I modify that file?

Comment: you have two ways: 1) modify the related html and provide that to sharepoint, then SP will create the js; 2) modify the js keeping consistency with what you can find there